# Give ftp users access to directories outside their root using symlinks

Tags: permissions, ftp, symbolic-link, chroot

I tried to give proftpd virtual users access to directories outside their home paths using symlinks I created as root through the console.

`/var/ftp/users/test`  is the home of the user named `test`.
`/var/ftp/files/documents`  is the directory that holds the documents, and `/var/ftp/users/test/documents`   is the symlink that points to it.

But when an user connects to the FTP and tries to follow the symlink, he only sees this error:

`documents: No such file or directory`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Symlinks are locked into the jail the same way the user is; otherwise it would be possible for the user to break out of the jail with `cd documents`.  (No, root-created symlinks can't be treated specially, for the same reason that `cd -P symlink-to-dir; cd ..` leaves you in the wrong place; the appearance of it working as you'd expect is an illusion created by the shell.)  Use a bind mount instead (`mount --bind /var/ftp/files/documents /var/ftp/users/test/documents`).

Comment: This needs to be done every time the server restarts, right?

Comment: Yes; you'll want to put it in `/etc/fstab`.

Comment: Just for example to help anyone else out, here are the mount and fstab quivelants:
**mount** `mount --bind /path/to/original/directory /path/to/mountpoint`
**fstab** `/path/to/original/directory /path/to/mountpoint none bind 0 0`

Comment: This works for me, even when the destination is on another mount point!  /mnt/....